# import spring.ftl cannout found

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

i'm upgrade my project from old boot 1.x to 2.3.12, and almost done but one thing is make problem.

In this project i used freemarker, so upgrade boot and used starter-freemarker.

server is going right well, but approach to some ftl page there's error that

```
cannout found in basePackagePath="/templates/" spring.ftl
```

I think some configuration is deny to approach library's ftl file, but there's no one get some trouble like me.

does anyone know about this?

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something replaces the `TemplateLoader` that Spring sets in the FreeMarker `Configuration` object. Spring used to set a `MultiTemplateLoader`, with one of the nested `TemplateLoader`-s loading from the classpath, with `org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker` as the base.

Comment: Hi Thx to reply. as you say i configure in custom config file.

Comment: can i as one more thing? i want to set template loader for import spring.ftl with custom config. but i can't know how to do this. every templateload like springtemplateloader / path / class / file but there is any correct path for spring.ftl. 

if know some thing or someone plz help.

Comment: `MultiTemplateLoader`, with one of its items being a `ClassTemplateLoader` with `basePackagePath` `/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker` should work. But also, Spring has its own `TemplateLoader` that can load from Spring "resources", and they use that, so that's probably a more future proof bet. Also, can you just not replace the template loader instead? You can still set the other settings. Spring even had a feature for you to add template loaders without replacing its own.